# No access to a linked container with docker run (mapping in /etc/hosts not exist)

Tags: docker

I have a running mysql container with name "drupaldistribution_mysql_1" (id 307b58c78108).

Now I want to start another container with a command tool named "drush", that has access to the mysql container. I use the command:

```
$ docker run --link 307b58c78108:db --volumes-from drupaldistribution_data_1 -w /data/www/drupal drush/drush sqlc && cat /etc/hosts
```

But the /etc/hosts file in the drush container does not contain the information about the linked container:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1 docker-host docker-host

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Docker inspect on the drush container returns:

```
$ docker inspect -f "{{ .HostConfig.Links }}" 7d5f4cea983e

[/drupaldistribution_mysql_1:/tender_banach/db]
```

I run the docker version: Docker version 1.6.2, build 7c8fca2 (inside of vagrant debian machine).

Why is there no reference in the hosts file about the linked mysql container?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is the issue is due to the `--volumes-from`. Try not to share data between your database and other containers.
When I try, I have the `127.0.1.1 docker-host docker-host` line though is it part of your local /etc/hosts?

Also, you can use the name with `--link` instead of the id.

Finally, if it still fails, you always can pull the ip from the environment. Make sure that your mysql image exposes a port and once you link it, you will have `DB_PORT_XXXX_TCP_ADDR` in the environment.

Comment: The problem is probably not caused by "--volumes-from". I have tryed the command only with the "--link" option and the result is the same:


`docker run --rm --link drupaldistribution_mysql_1:db drush/drush --version && cat /etc/hosts && env`


But the hosts file contains only the entry for the container (localhost) and the docker host (the vagrant machine) and not for the linked container. Also no environment variable for the db container is set. The mysql container expose a port.

Comment: This bash command will cat your host `/etc/hosts`. You should run it like this: `docker run --rm --link drupaldistribution_mysql_1:db --entrypoint bash drush/drush -c 'drush --version && cat /etc/hosts && env'`